# Service broker does not use user specified in the route

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2012, service-broker

I am trying to send the message from 1 server to another using windows login user. I created route for that:

```
CREATE ROUTE [SB_Server1_Server2Route]  
      AUTHORIZATION [COMPANY\SVC.SQLServiceBroker] 
      WITH SERVICE_NAME = '//Server1/Server2/UpdatedRecord_TargetService',
      ADDRESS = 'tcp://Server2:4022';
```

I am sending message using following query/procedure:

```
EXEC [dbo].[SB_SendBrokerMessage] '//Server1/Server2/UpdatedRecord_InitiatorService',
'//Server1/Server2/UpdatedRecord_TargetService', @XML;


CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[SB_SendBrokerMessage]
    @FromService sysname ,
    @ToService sysname ,
    @MessageBody XML
AS
    BEGIN
        SET NOCOUNT ON;
        IF ( @MessageBody IS NOT NULL
             AND @FromService IS NOT NULL
             AND @ToService IS NOT NULL
           )
            BEGIN
                DECLARE @conversation_handle UNIQUEIDENTIFIER;

                BEGIN TRANSACTION;

                BEGIN DIALOG CONVERSATION @conversation_handle
                    FROM SERVICE @FromService
                    TO SERVICE @ToService
                    WITH ENCRYPTION = OFF;

                SEND ON CONVERSATION @conversation_handle (@MessageBody);

                COMMIT TRANSACTION;
            END;
    END;
GO
```

And I am getting following error in the log:

> Service Broker login attempt by user 'COMPANY\AnotherUser.' failed
>   with error: 'Connection handshake failed. The login
>   'COMPANY\AnotherUser' does not have CONNECT permission on the
>   endpoint. State 84.'.  [CLIENT: 192.168.21.61]

So the question is: why it does not use the user specified in the route?

Answer (score 2):

The authorization clause on the route (or anything else) specifies who owns the route, not who people will connect as. Luckily, there's an easy fix for your situation: grant connect permission on the endpoint to whatever users need it.

Comment: Can I specify what user will be used to send the message and connect to remote endpoint? I granted permissions on the endpoint, however this user is not used for sending ...

Comment: Sure. Either run the procedure as the correct user or specify an `execute as` clause in the definition of the procedure (which will invoke impersonation for the context of the execution of the procedure).

Comment: I am not sure that I understood you right. I want to use UserA to send the message from Server1 to Server2. If I give grants to access endpoint then grants are validated only after the message is being sent. In my case I gave the UserA grants to connect to endpoint, however the message is sent by another user. How can I choose that UserA is supposed to do everything?

Comment: As I said in the previous comment, you either need to run your SB_SendBrokerMessage procedure as UserA, add an `execute as 'UserA'` clause to your stored procedure, or grant the appropriate permissions to the user that's actually running the procedure. As is the general case with any error, either change the system throwing the error or change the system that's interacting with it in such a way that the erroring system thinks that it's not an error any more. :)

Comment: I tried to create stored procedure with EXECUTE AS user - did not help. I also provided the right permissions to the endpoint - did not help either. I made workaround and gave permissions to the user who do it by default, but I would be nice to have separate user for that...

Comment: Out of curiosity, what are you actually trying to do? That is, why is it important to you who the message is delivered as?

Comment: The problem is with permissions. The problem is that when we send activated procedure is executed it uses linked server. And the user who actually executes the procedure does not have access rights to that linked server.

Comment: Ah. That's a different problem entirely. There are a couple of ways around that problem. Put an 'execute as' clause on the activated proc (for an account that does have permissions on the linked server), push the message to a broker on the far side of the linked server (if it only needs to access resources on that side), or (most simply) give permissions on the linked server to the right account(s).

Comment: Can not do EXECUTE AS. Getting error: "Access to the remote server is denied because the current security context is not trusted." and as the admin said that EXECUTE AS Windows_User is not working with the linked servers.

Answer (score 1):

Ben already told you why using the AUTHORIZATION clause has nothing to do with Service Broker connections.

To set up two instances to be able to exchange Service Broker messages you need to set up [Service Broker Transport Security](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms166092%28v=sql.105%29.aspx). You can choose between certificate based authentication (see [How does Certificate based authentication work](http://rusanu.com/2008/10/23/how-does-certificate-based-authentication-work/)) or Windows based authentication. The transport layer security has absolutely **nothing** to do with the current user. It does not matter what current user is running the Service Broker verbs, it only allows the two instances involved to connect to each other. I strongly recommend using certificate based authentication, but if you must* use Windows the you must grant CONNECT permission to the peer **service account**.

A second layer of security exists in Service Broker, namely dialog security (see [Conversations Authentication](http://rusanu.com/2008/11/04/conversations-authentication/)). This allows two Service Broker services to authenticate each other and exchange messages. This, again, has nothing to do with current connected user. If specified then it requires creation of [remote service binding](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178024.aspx) objects. Is always certificate based.

In the end, when all the Service Broker security is set up both at transport and at conversation layers, then you must also specify what SQL users have the permission to use this infrastructure, and this is controlled through the RECEIVE permission granted on the queue that hosts a service.